# how do I make full page slide websites with html & css?

Tags: html, css

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Muli';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Muli'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/minRpKQdEvXRRS8oAbAtWvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
}

body {
 font-family: 'Muli', Helvetica, Ariel, Georgia, serif;
 font-size: medium;
 margin: 0px;
}

#initial {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;

}

h1 {
 font-size: 3.5em;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
 border-color: red;
 border-style: solid;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 0px;
}

div.tableRow {
 display: table-row;
}

div.tableContainer {
 display: table;
}

#profile {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 250px;
 height: auto;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#bio_text {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

#ccb, #cfc {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 border-color: red;
 border-style: solid;
}

#contactForm {
 display: table-cell;
 border-color: red;
 border-style: solid;
}

#contactInfo {
 display: table-cell;
 border-color: red;
 border-style: solid;
}

#contactInfo ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
}

#contactInfo h2 {
 text-align: center;
}

footer {
 border-top-width: 1px;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-color: black;
 text-align: center;
}

footer ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
 border-color: red;
 border-style: solid;
}

footer p {
 text-align: center;
 border-color: red;
 border-style: solid;
}

footer ul li a:link, footer ul li a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chris Wang</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
 </head> 

 <body>
  <header>
   <img id="initial" src="img/background_final.jpg" alt="Chris Wang">
  </header>

  <section id="bio">
   <h1>Who Am I?</h1>
   <div class="tableContainer">
    <div class="tableRow">
     <div id="bio_text">
      <p>
       blah blah blah personal description
      </p>
      <p>
       personal description
      </p>
      <p>
       more personal stuffs
      </p>
      <p>
       more personal stuffs
      </p>
     </div>
     <img id="profile" src="img/profile_edit.jpg" alt="This is me!">
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

  <h1>What Have I Done?</h1>
  <section id="past">
   <div class="tableRow">
    <div id="ccb">
     <a href="pages/ccb/index.html">
      <img id="ccb_thumbnail" src="pages/ccb/img/thumbnail_resize.jpg" alt="Cranbrook Culture Book">
     </a>
    </div>

    <div id="cfc">
     <a href="pages/cfc/index.html">
      <img id="cfc_thumbnail" src="pages/cfc/img/thumbnail_resize.jpg" alt="Cranes for Change">
     </a>
    </div>

    <!--<div id="trombetta">
     <a href="pages/trombetta/index.html">
      <img id="trombetta_thumbnail" src="pages/trombetta/img/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Trombetta Intern">
     </a>
    </div>-->
   </div>
  </section>

  <h1>Let's Talk!</h1>

  <div class="tableContainer">
   <fieldset id="contactForm">
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <div class="tableRow">
     <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
     <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Steve Jobs" required>
    </div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableRow">
     <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="stevejobs@apple.com" required>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
     <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
     <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="(000)-000-0000">
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
     <label for="message">Message:</label>
     <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
     <label></label>
     <input type="submit" value="Send!">
    </div>
   </fieldset>

   <div id="contactInfo">
    <h2>Contact Info</h2>
    <ul>
     <li>Chris Wang</li>
     <li>chriswang.work</li>
     <li><a href="mailto:xxx@icloud.com" title="My Email">xxx@icloud.com</a> </li>
     <li><a href="tel:+##########" title="My Number">###-###-####</a></li>
    </ul>

    <img id="linkedin" src="img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn Account">
    <img id="twitter" src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Account">
   </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="homepage.html#bio" title="Bio">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="homepage.html#past" title="Experience">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="file/resume.pdf" title="Resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="pages/quotes/index.html" title="My Favorite Quotes">Quotes</a></li>
   </ul>

   <p>&copy; 2016 Chris Wang</p>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to build a personal website that has full page slides with just HTML & CSS (maybe a bit of super simple PHP for backend stuff), here's an example of what I'm talking about: http://www.hannahsilverton.com

Now I used the max height and weight rule for the opening slide with a jpeg where I layered my initial on top of a cool pic with photoshop. However, when I can't seem to figure out how to make my 2 paragraph bio w/ picture into a full page slide.

Furthermore, I'm also having trouble on the past experience section. I want to have them in the form of a couple of cards across the screen (2 or 3 per roll). However, when I used table display w/ css, all it does is putting the two cards right next to each other (same result as if I was using inline).

Thanks in advance! I just learned the language about a month ago, so excuse me if I make any noob mistake :P

Lastly, if anyone wants to see the code I have now, comment below and I'll inbox you.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you show us your code? Please create a **working** [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) with your html and css.

Comment: Sure! hang on let me figure out how to do it really quickly

Comment: see this site: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage
or this (fullPage.js +Bootstrap 3): http://demo.w3developer.de/fullpage/#home

Comment: I don't understand why people would down vote this, it's a valid question

Comment: @AdamP. I haven't learned how to implement js into my codes yet. Do you know if there's any way to achieve this with just css and html?

Comment: I found this (not scroll slide, only click slide [right to left]): only CSS & HTML: http://www.cssscript.com/full-width-horizontal-page-slider-with-pure-html-css/

(modification can not help you, I am not familiar with CSS transitions)

Comment: @ChrisWang because its not a question but more a "i dont get it please code it for me" and thats not what so is made for

Comment: @TomDoodler all I'm asking is to point me in the right direction, eg: try out xxx display or something like that. How would that be code it for me?

Comment: So the first question that comes to my mind is: Do you want to scroll freely through the page like in the example you are giving or do you want to "snap" to each new slide like [here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#4thpage)?

Comment: @TomDoodler I'm thinking more for free scrolling because it's probably easier to implement, but I'm open for both

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a complete answer, but I assume you dont want a complete solution but a step for step guide, so I take the risk of getting downvoted. Here we go:

- Create the CSS for a "slide" or "page", propably divs, which have `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;`. Put them in another div, class `content`, also `width: 100%; height: 100%;` or so. It will contain all of the slides. Make the `content` div `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;`
- If you want to "snap" to each slide, you have to get there via javascript and propably some kind of framework, there is an extension for jQuery which provides mousewheel-listeners which i tend to use quite often but its up to you which one youd like to use.

So basically thats the most important steps, look at this example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bs77L2g0/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I don't understand why anyone would down vote this or the difference between a "complete" solution and this. I totally follow your train of thoughts, but, if you don't mind me asking, wouldn't width and height 100% just make the content take up as much space as they need, no more but no less? So in this case wouldn't it be impossible for there to be full screen slides on a larger screen since 3 paragraphs for example would not constitute an entire screen so it'll still end up looking like the one I have up there? Also, what does overflow-x and -y do here?

Comment: Oh and once again, excuse me for the boob questions, I literally began to code just last month, so I suck at it a lot lol I'm asking a lot of questions because I'm just trying to learn the why behind how's here

Comment: Np, `height: 100%;` means that the div will take the height of its parent, which in this case is `content`, which is exactly the screen height because its parent is `body` which we told to be `100%` height (i think that wouldnt be necessary but just to make sure) so the slide's width will be your screen width, same with height, no matter how much it contains

Comment: and `overflow-x` means "how should i handle the content, which exceeds the divs bounds in x direction", it can either be `auto` : make scrollbars if necessary, `hidden`: dont show overlapping content at all or `scroll`: make scrollbars, no matter if anything overlaps, same with `overflow-y`